# web.config siteMap element ignored

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

The `siteMap` element in my `web.config` is being ignored. Why is this?
My objective is to get the `siteMapNodeUrlResolver` in effect.

**web.config**

```xml
  <system.web>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider"
             type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             siteMapFile=""
             securityTrimmingEnabled="true"
             cacheDuration="5"
             enableLocalization="false"
             scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true"
             excludeAssembliesForScan=""
             includeAssembliesForScan="AACOMvc"
             attributesToIgnore=""
             nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             siteMapNodeUrlResolver="AACOMvc.SiteMapNodeUrlResolver, AACOMvc"
             siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider"
         />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

**SiteMapNodeUrlResolver.cs**

```cs
using MvcSiteMapProvider;
using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.UrlResolver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AACOMvc
{
  public class SiteMapNodeUrlResolver : ISiteMapNodeUrlResolver
  {
    public SiteMapNodeUrlResolver() : base() { }

    public bool AppliesTo(string providerName)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException(); // line never executes
    }

    public string ResolveUrl(ISiteMapNode node, string area, string controller, string action, IDictionary<string, object> routeValues)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException(); // line never executes
    }
  }
}
```

When I help the provider find my resolver by setting the `urlResolver` attribute on a node, it finds it. But then I get:

> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type
>   'AACOMvc.SiteMapNodeUrlResolver' not found.

1. I would rather specify my resolver globally than specify `urlResolver` attribute. The attribute defeats the purpose of specifying the resolver in the first place which is merely to clean up and minimize the sitemap file.
2. Once it finds the resolver I need it working

So I guess two related issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MvcSiteMapProvider` v4 ignores the legacy ASP.NET 2.0 web.config settings - this is by design. Configuration is now done 100% through dependency injection, but there are some `appSettings` that you can use for basic configurations without using an external DI container. Refer to the documentation:

- https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider
- https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4#updating-configuration